# TextView and ImageView are not working

Tags: android, xml

I have 2 TextView and one ImageView and I set value for them... but they don't show anything!...

I transferred value from first java activity to second java activity using putExtra. The data transfer successfully but not display in textView and imageview!!

please help!

**here is my HotelPage.java :**

```
package ir.homa;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by SMQ on 7/17/2016.
 */
public class HotelPage extends Activity {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<HotelList> hotelList;
    private String name;
    private int numOfRooms;
    private int thumbnail;


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title1, count1;
        public ImageView thumbnail1;

        public RelativeLayout card;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            title1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title1);
            count1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.count1);
            thumbnail1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbnail1);
        }
    }

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.hotel_page);

            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            name = extras.getString("name");
            numOfRooms = extras.getInt("count");
            thumbnail = extras.getInt("thumbnail");
        }

    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        final HotelList hotel = hotelList.get(position);

        holder.title1.setText(name);
        holder.count1.setText(numOfRooms + " اتاق");

        // loading hotel cover using Glide library
        Glide.with(mContext).load(thumbnail).into(holder.thumbnail1);

    }

}
```

**And here is my hotel_page.xml :**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/title1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/count1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So, Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You are.. Combining an `Activity` with a `RecyclerviewAdapter`.. You should separate them.. And it's not even the problem, I'll tell you the steps!

1. Add ids to each and every `TextView` and `ImageView` like :

`android:id="+@id/textView1"`

2. Get reference to it from `onCreate` of your `Activity` like :

`TextView title1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title1);`

3. Set text to it by :

`title1.setText(name);`

You shouldn't use holder like that as it is mostly used in `RecyclerViewAdapter`